# How do I create an event that tracks how frequently users login in Mixpanel?

Tags: python, mixpanel

I'm working in Python, and I'm trying to write a small program that creates an event (`log_in`) and can give me a list of all previous logins by user id (`user_id`).

I have my API keyword and secret, as well as my Mixpanel project token.

I'm a beginner so please be gentle.

Comment: Welcome to SO!  What have you tried?  See [how to ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and create a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: Gently speaking, SO is not a coding service. We're happy to help you understand and solve problems you run into while trying to create your program but we don't do it for you.